# Remove Emojis from PosgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have emojis in my PosgreSQL table:

[image: Emojis]

which I need to remove.

I used a script:

```
select full_name,  
       ltrim(rtrim(regexp_replace(full_name, '[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', 'g'))) as Cleansed_Name
from Emoji_Test
```

It removes the emoji from "Amie Bartly Fashion Blogger" which is good but transforms "Amina Öztürk  to "Amina  zt rk" which is not good.

What can I do to remove only emojis and keep pertinent name information?

Comment: Hi, can you try A-zÀ-ú ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on a database here and just changed the regex you used.

**Query**

```
select firstname, regexp_replace(firstname, '[^A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ]', ' ', 'g') from person where firstname ilike '%débora%';
```

**Output**
`Débora❤️,Débora`

Comment: Hey GabrielNexT,

Comment: Hey @GabrielNexT,

Yes, that's correct - but it changes "Amina Öztürk"     to     "Amina zt rk" which is not good.
So the script removes more than just emojis. I need it to only remove emojis.

Comment: @Prem I edited my answer, can you test the new regex?

Comment: Hey @GabrielNexT,

Thank you for that, it did indeed work that name, however, I see that:
"Abdullah Çağın" was changed to "Abdullah Ça  n".

I guess, in order to cater to each name scenario, I would need to edit the script on to add them in?

Comment: @Prem I was more concerned with accents, but I see there are symbols too. Isn't it better you generate a txt with the names? This makes it easier for the community to help you find a valid regex.